# How can I get more memory in "Oracle R Enterprise"?

Tags: r, oracle

How can I increase memory for ORE? 
My server have 10G free memory, but I can't use all of them for ORE.
These commands have error:

```
begin
sys.rqscriptDrop('clustering_test');
sys.rqscriptcreate('clustering_test','function(n){
                                        rm(list=ls())
                                        cnt=30000
                                        d=dist(data.frame(x=rnorm(cnt),
                                                          y=rnorm(cnt)))
                                        }');
end;
```

(for run above R script you can run this):

```
select * from table(rqtableeval(cursor(select 1 n from dual), 
                                cursor(select 1 "ore.connect" from dual), 
                    'select 1 x, 2 y from dual','clustering_test'))
```

But these commands could run on R in server:

```
cnt=30000
d=dist(data.frame(x=rnorm(cnt),y=rnorm(cnt)))
```

They are same code, but one of them ran directly on R and another through ORE.

- cnt depends to your free system RAM.
- - error in ORE has not any description. but if you decrease cnt that could run.

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe increase parameter `MAX_VSIZE` (or maybe `MAX_NSIZE` if the problem isn't vectors but cons.) See ORE Administrative Tasks manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e36763/ore_admin.htm#CACBAGCI

Comment: I have set 'MAX_VSEZE' and 'MAX_NSIZE' to null  (unlimited).

Comment: What is the server OS?

Comment: It's windows server 2008(release2 )